# How to configure Azure App Service (for Mobile) and B2C Authentication and access Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-mobile-services

I have a xamarin.forms mobile App using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices and Microsoft.Identity.Client. Using EasyAuth I successfully got the xamarin mobile app to post data to the AzureSQL tables linked via connection string in the App Service configuration section. I use the local and offline sync methods of MobileServiceClient. I then attempted to change to B2C authentication. I setup a Tenant and under this tenant registered a new App as a native client called "MobileB2C". Redirect URIs were added automatically. I then created the signinsignup UserFlows.

Back to the Azure App Service (Mobile) under Authentication section I added a provider and selected the B2C App, MobileB2C. I did not populate the "allowed token audiences" field and Azure automatically created Client secret setting name "MICROSOFT_PROVIDER_AUTHENTICATION_SECRET" and the issuer URL.

So when I run the xamarin mobile app I can login via azure B2C and I can see that the **authResult** returns the users correct info along with UserIdentifier,aud, iss, sub, oid etc.

Once authResult is returned the xamarin mobile then tries to use the sync methods of MobileServiceClient to save data to the AzureSQL table. Its at this point that it fails. When the line `await mClient.SyncContext.PushAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);`  is hit an error occurs described as **Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync.MobileServicePushStatus.CancelledByAuthentication**. I continued to try and confirgure the Azure back end differently and now I no linger get the CancelledByAuthentication error but instead get **Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync.MobileServicePushStatus.CancelledByNetworkError**.

The relevant xamarin mobile app code to implement the authentication and AzureSQL table update is as follows;

```
private B2CAuthenticationService()
    {

        // default redirectURI; each platform specific project will have to override it with its own
        var builder = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(B2CConstants.ClientID)
            .WithB2CAuthority(B2CConstants.AuthoritySignInSignUp)
            .WithIosKeychainSecurityGroup(B2CConstants.IOSKeyChainGroup)
            .WithRedirectUri($"msal{B2CConstants.ClientID}://auth");

        // Android implementation is based on https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin
        // iOS implementation would require to expose the current ViewControler - not currently implemented as it is not required
        // UWP does not require this
        var windowLocatorService = DependencyService.Get<IParentWindowLocatorService>();

        if (windowLocatorService != null)
        {
            builder = builder.WithParentActivityOrWindow(() => windowLocatorService?.GetCurrentParentWindow());
        }

        _pca = builder.Build();
    }

    public async Task<UserContext> SignInAsync()
    {
        UserContext newContext;
        try
        {
            // acquire token silent
            newContext = await AcquireTokenSilent();
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
        {
            // acquire token interactive
            newContext = await SignInInteractively();
        }
        return newContext;
    }
    private async Task<UserContext> SignInInteractively()
    {
        AuthenticationResult authResult = await _pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(B2CConstants.Scopes)
            .ExecuteAsync();

        var newContext = UpdateUserInfo(authResult);
        UserSingleton.Instance.UserId = newContext.UserIdentifier;
        return newContext;
    }
```

THe xamarin mobile app adds a record to the local database and then RefreshItemsAsync begins the synchronisation to the AzureSQL.

await azureService.AddUserSurveyAsync(newSurvey).ConfigureAwait(false);
await azureService.RefreshItemsAsync(true).ConfigureAwait(false);

It is at the PushAsync line below that the the code fails.

```
    public async Task InitializeAsync()
        {
            using (await initializationLock.LockAsync())
            {
                if (!isInitialized)
                {
                    mClient = new MobileServiceClient(https://mobileservice.azurewebsites.net);

                    // Define the offline store.
                    mStore = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore("mobile3.db");
                    mStore.DefineTable<UserSurvey>();
                    await mClient.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(mStore, new MobileServiceSyncHandler()).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    UserSurveyTable = mClient.GetSyncTable<UserSurvey>();
                    isInitialized = true;
                }
            }
        }

    public async Task RefreshItemsAsync(bool syncItems)
    {
            if (syncItems)
            {
                await SynchronizeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
    }

    public async Task SynchronizeAsync()
    {
        await InitializeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        IReadOnlyCollection<MobileServiceTableOperationError> syncErrors = null;

        if (!CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
            return;

        try
        {
            await mClient.SyncContext.PushAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            await UserSurveyTable.PullAsync("usersurveys", UserSurveyTable.CreateQuery()).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (MobileServicePushFailedException error)
        {
            if (error.PushResult != null)
            {
                foreach (var result in error.PushResult.Errors)
                {
                    await ResolveError(result);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What is wrong with the Azure back end configuration or perhaps I'm missing code as I can't understand how the xamarin mobile app can then attempt to communicate with the Azure Mobile App Service and AzureSQL as I don't send any token with those lines of code for PushAsync etc or perhaps this is abstracted away?

Here are images of the exceptions;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEKlN.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVRwu.png)

Comment: You need to take a peek into the exception being generated on conflict (CancelledByAuthentication / CancelledByNetworkError) - both of these exceptions have additional information about what the service is returning.  Set a break point in your code and inspect the exception.

Comment: Adrian I have posted above images of the exception information. There is still nothing there that I can interpret and work with so any further suggestions more than welcome!

Comment: I can see two potential issues.  1) It is an AAD authentication secret, not a MICROSOFT authentication secret.  MICROSOFT indicates "outlook.com" (aka MSA) authentication.  2) I didn't see where you actually logged in - maybe it is elsewhere?

Comment: After that, add a LoggingDelegatingHandler to your project that logs the requests and responses - you should be able to see what is going on under the hood.  You can add delegating handlers to the HTTP stack using the MobileServiceClient(serviceUrl, new DelegatingHandler1()...)

Comment: Adrian I will add the logging handler. I do not understand your point for the frst issue. Yes I am using Microsofts AAD B2C MSAL authentication. In the above method Task<UserContext> SignInInteractively() is where I assume I sign in. At least authResult does return information which includes the ClientID etc expected in the token (I looked at it with http://jwt.ms) and I can see via Azure portal that user in the Tenant has signed in. So what is the significance of your comment that it is not a MICROSOFT authentication secret?

Comment: There are two authentication providers in Azure Mobile Apps - "aad" and "microsoft" and that corresponds to two authentication providers in Azure App Service, each with their own client id/secret.  The MICROSOFT_PROVIDER_AUTHENTICATION_SECRET is for "microsoft", not "aad".  You need to set up the authentication provider as an AAD provider.  ("microsoft" is for outlook.com auth, not AAD based auth)

Comment: Adrian I removed MICROSOFT_PROVIDER_AUTHENTICATION_SECRET. Still no joy. Can I check with you the App Service setup? In the B2C tenants App registration I registered a new app (call it B2CApp) and set it up for MSAL etc. My xamarin.forms app authenticates correctly. My xam app trys to connect to another App Service (call it MobileApp) I created with a DB registered to it. In MobileApp I setup its Authentication by putting the B2CApp from above as its identity provider. Is this correct? Because I cannot get through to the MobileApp database as I did before with same code but no authentication)

Comment: No - it's not.  It took me quite a while to understand authentication, so I'll share in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As promised, here is the succinct version of AAD authentication.  For your purposes, B2C authentication is the same as AAD authentication.

There are two application definitions at play here - one for the mobile application (which basically says "this person is authenticated"), and one for the service (which says "a token authenticated for this mobile application can access this service").  So, you create an application ID for your mobile application, and an application ID for your service, and then you configure the service application ID to accept the mobile application.

The "WPF" tutorial for Azure Mobile Apps gives the general overview, although it's for WPF instead of Xamarin.  The pieces you need are all the same.

The "WPF" tutorial here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/azure-mobile-apps/quickstarts/wpf/authentication

Comment: Right well I will start on it. First time through the tutorial I'm getting error: {Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException: You do not have permission to view this directory or page at await mClient.LoginAsync("aad", new JObject(new JProperty("access_token", userContext.AccessToken))); but I have seen some activity in the logs for Data In/Out, Response time etc on the App Service so thats not happened before         . I will keep trying to work it out and post again if I get stuck. Thanks again for responding Adran

Comment: Adrian, When I use the native app Client ID in the xamarin app I get error at authentication step saying the applicaiton with CLient ID of native client is not valid against this service. I sent you an email to you @ photoadrian.. Do you reply to these?

Comment: I now get an access_token, but have problem with the MobileServiceClient LoginAsync. I get an error 401.83 UnAuthorized "The authenticated user does not have access to a resource needed to process the request". have tried all stackoverflow suggestions and need advice. I tried different things for the allowed token audience under the authentication section of the resource. The https:// ??.azurewebsite.net/.auth/login/aad/callack and also the Client IDs that are in the token for the "aud" property. From Azure diagnotics logs Im only getting the 401.83 info for the error. Running out of ideas

Comment: oh forgot to add I have created an application ID for mobile application, and an application ID for service, and configured the service application ID to accept the mobile application and used the service to protect the resource (app service with SQL Db).

Comment: This is no longer a problem with the mobile app, then, but more a permissions issue with AADB2C and App Service.

Comment: Maybe. I have raised a ticket with Azure Auth and App Service engineer so hoping I can get some guidance. Why isn't there a simple, step by step, field by field guide on how to configure Azure for what must be a pretty common scenario. Lets hope some guy writes an online book on it and puts me out of my misery!

Comment: the feedback from the Azure Auth Engineer is that the Web App for the Service  cannot be used for B2C. Instead use Bearer token HTTPS

At the moment I understand this means I cannot use "await MobileServiceClient.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory, zumoPayload);"

Will report back once I read up on bearer token HTTPS. Still not sure though whether I still protect the Resource with the Web App or how that will work.